# Operations on Date Field from online data - sqldf

Tags: r, sqldf

I am  working with an online data set that has dates. I am trying to perform operations based on dates using R (sqldf) but it does not work. I can solve my problem using other packages, but I would to resolve this by limiting my analysis using SQL queries.

I will start by showing what I want to do using a simple example and a local data set:

```
library(sqldf)
Name <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
DOB <- c('1989-08-19','1993-07-14', '1982-12-16', '1934-11-04', '2010-02-19')
dt1 <- data.frame(Name, DOB)
dt1
str(dt1)
```

Using this I can calculate age using sqldf as follows and get the correct results:

```
sqldf("select name, current_date, DOB from dt1")
sqldf("select name, current_date, DOB, current_date-DOB as AGE from dt1")
sqldf("select name, current_date, DOB, current_date-DOB as AGE from dt1 
  where DOB >'1990-01-01'")
```

I have created exactly the same data set in Google drive and I am trying to replicate the above script.

```
library(gsheet)
dt2 <- gsheet2tbl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E3lFgsee9FZL0NERAyDwRYvYqpjsMJ-9aLzj9rJcBc4/edit?usp=sharing")
dt2
str(dt2)
sqldf("select name, current_date, DOB from dt2")
sqldf("select name, current_date, DOB, current_date-DOB as AGE from dt2")
sqldf("select name, current_date, DOB, current_date-DOB as AGE from dt2 
  where DOB >'1990-01-01'")
```

It returns age in the thousands of years!

Tried to change the date format

```
dt2 <- gsheet2tbl("Same as Above")
str(dt2)
dt2
dt2$DOB <- as.Date(dt$DOB, "%y/%m/%d")
str(dt2)
dt2
```

I am stuck since the DOB has become NAs, so I tried a different format for date

```
dt2 <- gsheet2tbl("Same as Above")
str(dt2)
dt2
dt2$DOB <- as.Date(dt2$DOB, "%y-%m-%d")
str(dt2)
dt2
```

Same problem, so I tried to convert to factors

```
dt2 <- gsheet2tbl("Same as above")
str(dt2)
dt2
dt2$DOB <- as.factor(dt2$DOB)
str(dt2)
dt2
sqldf("select name, current_date, DOB from dt2")
sqldf("select name, current_date, DOB, current_date-DOB as AGE from dt2")
sqldf("select name, current_date, DOB, current_date-DOB as AGE from dt2 
  where DOB >'1990-01-01'")
```

Back to square one, age is in thousands of years!
Any suggestions on how to solve this using SQL queries would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

PS I have the same problem when I download the data and import it as csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm will not give you the proper AGE if you operate on string variables. Here's how you could do it:

```
library(gsheet)
dt2 <- gsheet2tbl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E3lFgsee9FZL0NERAyDwRYvYqpjsMJ-9aLzj9rJcBc4/edit?usp=sharing")

# Convert date to a "real date"
dt2$DOB <- as.Date(dt2$DOB, "%m/%d/%Y")

# Add today's date, also as a "real date"
dt2$today <- as.Date(Sys.Date())

# Perform calculation for age
sqldf("select name, today, DOB, floor((today-DOB)/365.25) as AGE from dt2")
```

### Results

```
  Name      today        DOB AGE
1    A 2016-06-20 1989-08-19  26
2    B 2016-06-20 1993-07-14  22
3    C 2016-06-20 1982-12-16  33
4    D 2016-06-20 1934-11-04  81
5    E 2016-06-20 2010-02-19   6
```

**EDIT following OP's comment...**

For the 3rd query, we could include the cutoff date in the table as we did with the `today` column, or use the following alternative:

```
sqldf(paste0("select name, today, DOB, floor((today-DOB)/365.25) as AGE from dt2 where DOB > ", 
             as.integer(as.Date('1990-01-01'))))
```

### Results for 3rd query

```
  Name      today        DOB AGE
1    B 2016-06-20 1993-07-14  22
2    E 2016-06-20 2010-02-19   6
```

Comment: This works for the 1st and 2nd query, but it generates zero rows when I try the 3rd one.                                                                                                     > sqldf("select name, today, DOB, floor((today-DOB)/365.25) as AGE from dt2 where DOB >'1990-01-01'")
[1] Name  today DOB   AGE  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Comment: Right... Pls see my  edit... since column DOB is numerical (although it is displayed in human-readable format), you need to compare it with another numerical date.

Comment: Works! Thank you for your time.

Comment: You're welcome! Pls don't forget to upvote and/or accept this answer as a solution, it will also earn you rep points.